# Cant get the show on click function on jQuery to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, show

I cant get my jQuery to work.

I want the text "Show more" when the div is closed, then "Show less" when it is open.

This text works when it opens, but when it closes it wont change..

```
    $('.more_content').click(function(){
        $('p.show').text($('p.show').is(':visible') ? 'Show less' : 'Show more');
        $('#extra_content').slideToggle('fast')              
    });
```

Comment: well that's because you're not hiding it, so it's always visible.

Answer (score 2):

The statement

```
$('p.show').is(':visible')
```

should be:

```
$('#extra_content').is(':visible')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.more_content').click(function(){
$('#extra_content').is(':visible') ? $('p.show').text('Läs mer om oss') : $('p.show').text('Läs mindre om oss') ;
$('#extra_content').slideToggle('fast')
enter code here});
```